# How to access an object inside a ViewController from within a TableViewCell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, object, viewcontroller

I am fairly new at coding in swift and I've been trying to find a solution to my problem for the past couple days, and am not able to.

I have a class named `userData` with various properties:

```
class UserData {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var credits: Int = 1
    ...

    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

Inside the **viewController.swift** I have declared an object of this class:

```
...
var user = UserData(name: "testing", age: 5)
...
```

Inside the same `viewController` I have a `UITableView` with a few `UITableViewCells`. In every cell there is a `UIStepper`

Using the `UIStepper` from a cell I want to increment or decrement the property `credits` of my object `user` that sits inside the **viewController.swift**, and do that from within the **tableViewCell.swift** file

From what I can find, I think I should use a delegate but I can figure out how to implement it.

**More information:**
Pardon the art work, I am not an artist...

[image: my app image]

The user has a set amount of ants available to work (this number is a property of my object user). There is also a property for the amount of ants currently working ('ants used' in my screen shot).

At first, the white label on top says '0/5' (Meaning the user has 5 available ants to work but none are currently working).

When the user increments the stepper for 'scavenger ants', the white label on top should say '1/5' (Meaning that there is currently 1 ant working out of 5 that are available).

What I want to do, is that when the user clicks on a stepper, the user's property for the 'ants currently working' increments or decrements appropriately.

Thank you

Comment: Makes no sense. Multiple steppers but just one user? But each stepper can have a different value so hows that going to work?

Comment: Is there one or many usersData object ?

Comment: There is only one, I was planning to save the games progress inside a user object that would contain all ressources acquired and such. But there probably is a better way.

Comment: is credit the amount of ants available ?

Comment: No, credits is going to be some kind of money acquired by selling ressources farmed by the ants, but I have a property called antzCurrentAmount, and antzMaximumAmount.

Comment: @YannMorinCharbonneau I believe you would have to use _delegation pattern_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set that logic up in the view controllers' `cellForRowAt`.

When setting up the cell, you can add a function inside your view controller as the target every-time the UIStepper value changes:

```
// inside cellForRowAtIndexPath:
cell.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doSomething(sender:), for: .valueChanged)
```

Inside `doSomething` you set up the logic for updating your model.

```
func doSomething(sender: UIStepper) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Edit with an example of the delegate pattern which would be a better solution, for future readers.

First create a protocol:

```
protocol StepperCellDelegate {
    func didChangeValueForStepper(inCell: Cell, whateverInfoYouWantHere:...)
    func otherUsefulFunctions(...)
}
```

In your cell class, set a target/action for when your value is changed:

```
// inside the cell's initialization (`init(style:reuseIdentifier:)`
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged(sender:), for: .valueChanged)
```

Your cell also needs a delegate property:

```
weak var stepperCellDelegate: StepperCellDelegate?
```

`doSomething` would look something like this:

```
func valueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
    stepperCellDelegate?.didChangeValueForStepper(inCell: self, ...)
}
```

Your ViewController will implement the protocol

```
extension MyViewController: StepperCellDelegate {
    func didChangeValueForStepper(inCell: Cell, whateverInfoYouWantHere:...) {
        // implementation here
    }

    func otherUsefulFunctions(...){
        // implementation here
    }
}
```

And inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set itself as the delegate:

```
// inside cellForRowAtIndexPath:
cell.stepperCellDelegate = self
```

Comment: sounds interesting, I'll give it a try and get back to you! thank you

Comment: It is working!! Now, do you know if I can send two parameters to 'doSomething'? Like anything that would allow me to know from which tableViewCell the stepper is located?

Comment: You can use a [tag](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag) as an index to mark each UIStepper. A different approach would be to create a protocol like `StepperCellDelegate` with a method `didChangeValueForStepper(inCell: Cell, whateverInfoYouWantHere:...)`. You do the target/action thing inside the Cell, which fires a method that calls your delegate with the info you want to pass.

Comment: Awesome, I will use tags for now as it seems easier and I will focus on learning more about delegates in the future because I don't quite get how those work. But thank you, I will mark you as the solution!

Comment: Thanks. A delegate here really is the cleaner solution, as it is more generic and reusable. But if you're still in the process of learning swift I think doing it in the view controller is fine.

Comment: @YannMorinCharbonneau I edited my answer explaining how you'd setup a delegate, in case you are ever interested.

Comment: Wow thanks, I'll take a look at it and try to implement that

Answer (score 1):

Delegation is the proper way of handling this.

That UItableviewCell — both appear to be similar —
 should expose a protocol with a set of methods
 that the UIViewController can implement. Methods are 
triggered when you tap on the UIStepper widget.

Best to stick to this methodology,  and reuse it everywhere. Makes 
things manageable loosely coupled.